# How to check whether a value is in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm running in to a problem with my code. What needs to happen is:

- Program asks what your movie channel name is,
- Program asks what the code is that you received,
- Program checks whether the code you received matches the movie channel you specified,
- Program returns a print statement based on the result. If the code was found, print "Match", otherwise print "not found"

The code I have so far is:

```
def code_controle():
    moviechannel = input("What is the name of your movie channel?")
    code = input("What is the code you want to check?")
    list =  [
        ["RTL8", "20:30", "Rush", "John", "Smith", "123"],
        ["Veronica", "15:00", "V for Vendetta", "Jane", "Smith" , "ABC"]
        ]
```

Now what I need to do is match the `moviechannel` with a `code`.

Basically, if I put in "RTL8" and the code "123" it should look through all the lists starting with RTL8, then check the code I put in, with the code in the list. If this matches each other, print "match".

Comment: So what have you tried, and what is the problem? Note that naming your own list `list` is a very bad idea, as it prevents you from easily accessing the built-in.

Comment: Hello Jon, 

I only named my list, list, because it's an example for StackOverflow. My code looks different and is in Dutch. But the fundamentals are exactly the same.

Comment: Really you should be using dictionaries, or python pandas.

Comment: Try things in the interactive prompt.

Comment: Is the channel always the first item and the code always the 6th and last?

Comment: @PeterWood, yeah because I am reading it from a .csv file. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to iterate over the main list and check if the movie and code both exist in any sublist.

Python allows for checking values in a list using `in`. It is simply `if 'value' in list`

Writing a method as the one below could be useful if you want to call it often.

```
for sublist in list:
    if movie in sublist and code in sublist:
         return True
return False
```

**Edit:**
The above code will return true even if the movie and code values are interchanged. If the code is an unique identifier it should be fine, as no movie title would match it.

Since the list is generated by reading from an .csv file, and we are assured that the movie will always be the first item and the code the sixth, we can use the below code for exactly matching only those values.

```
for sublist in list:
    if (movie == sublist[0]) and (code == sublist[5]):
         return True
return False
```

I would wrap that in a `try/except` to catch any Index out of range just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you Resley. Well explained, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Still works because we're are checking in the same list twice. The positions don't matter, only the value does

Comment: No, it will be wrong. It will match with movie `RTL8`.

Comment: @PeterWood since Cake has clarified that the movie and code will always be at the same position, we could compare directly with those values. This should solve your issue. I'm editing my answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle that using python dictionaries, but to continue with your example:

```
found=0
for x in list: #note, change this, list is a type def
  if x[0]==code and x[-1]==channel:
      found+=1
      print "Match"
if (found==0):
  print "No match"
```

Comment: This checks for 123 but not for RTL8

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>> my_list = set([moviechannel] + [code])
>>> for x in list:
...     if len(set(x) & my_list) == 2:
...         print "Match"
... 
Match
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is what you mean:

```
for line in list:
    if moviechannel in line and code in line:
        print('Match')
        return
print('not found')
```

Btw you really should reconsider renaming your `list`, since that is also a built in function.

Comment: Hey,

Thank you for replying. This is probably the easiest way for me to get what I want. So thank you for that.

However, when I use your code... It first prints "not found" and then "found", probably because it checks every row in order. How can I make sure it ONLY prints "found" OR "not found" once? Instead of doing it for every single row.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to do it:

```
new_list = c_list[0] + c_list[1]
if code in new_list and moviechannel in new_list:
    print 'Match'
else:
    print 'Not found'
```

You should not use `list` as `list` is a built-in function so I changed it to `c_list`.